# How did they make this tab view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to make a tab view like this one:

[image]

What's the idea behind it?

Thanks

Comment: something like this https://github.com/RafaelKayumov/RKTabView or this https://github.com/cemolcay/CategorySliderView or... there are many more...

Comment: or this https://github.com/apascual/APHorizontalMenu

Comment: Thanks @TonyMkenu I'll check them out. Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A think of a `UISegmentedControl` with a custom appearance...

At least, that's the way I would do so...

Comment: Thanks @Zaphod. I did the same indeed with a UISegmentedControl

Comment: Cool! May be you could accept my answer, because a couple of grumpy downvoters have not think it was interesting enough! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, a menu bar like this is normally a customized UISegmentedControl.  
 You can find pre-made libraries for this type of menu bars.
This is a great one I have used called SDSegmentedControl: https://github.com/rs/SDSegmentedControl

Comment: Thanks @Georgio Sayegh I'll have a look